# Read messages off Azure ServiceBus queue and execute code

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-worker-roles

I have an application that uploads files to Azure Storage as blobs. Each time a file is uploaded, some code (written in Java) needs to be executed to download and process the blob's underlying file. In order to do this, I modified the application to write a message to an Azure ServiceBus queue once a file is added to the storage service.

What is a recommended cloud computing pattern to invoke the code for each message received off the queue? I am looking at the Worker role which appears to be VM based. Is there a way to spin up a worker when a message is added to the queue?

Comment: `Is there a way to spin up a worker when a message is added to the queue?` - Do take a look at Azure Functions with Service Bus Queue binding. No need to go Worker Role route.

Comment: @GauravMantri are Azure Functions not meant for execution of light-weight code? The code I intend to run for each message received (corresponding to each file uploaded to Azure Storage) is quite heavy.

Comment: Under `consumption plan`, each function can execute for a maximum of 5 minutes. If you think your code will need more time than that, you can always go for app service plans.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am not familiar with more complex usages of Azure Functions. The code is in the form of a fairly complex application with a lot of dependency JARs. That's why I was skeptical if an Azure function is up to the job.

Comment: hi  i currently use a web job which is set to continuous, this listens to any messages that drop on the queue and then processes them, if complete then they are removed from queue, be aware of dead letter queue as if this builds up then you may run out of space on the queue and no messages will be stored, this is done as a console app and publish to a web job.  Have been told that Azure Functions should be able to do this and be a lot cheaper but cannot confirm yet.

Comment: @MarkWest my preliminary understanding about web jobs is that they are related with IIS. My requirement is middleware-like. Also Azure Functions support .NET or JavaScript only, and not Java, plus the processing that needs to happen is non-trivial and involves multiple classes and function calls. Does the processing in your web job rely on IIS in any way? There does not appear to be any request-response model in the way you described your process.